# Can't create new instance after installing Angular 2 through CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use @angular cli to create a new angular 2 project. The install went well, but when I try to create a new site, I get the following error. Has anyone run into this?

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:15
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Actually, looks like @angular cli didn't install. I can't get a --version and when I look at the install results, I see the following warnings:

```
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/tsc-wrapped@^0.5.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: When you say 'create a new site', what do you mean? You tried running `ng new <name of new project>`?

Comment: Hi Gabriele, correct.

Comment: The error I display in my original post is the result of typing in "ng new <project>

Comment: can you add the version of angular-cli to the question

Comment: Looks like it wasn't actually installed. I can't get a --version and I just looked at the install results and there are the errors listed above.

Comment: have you searched through the issues on the ng2 github page to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your Nodejs version is out of date? Make sure you have the latest LTS 6.x